# MongoDB $where query with white space in field name

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB to make a $where request, as follow:

```
db.statistiquesClients.find({$where : function() { return (this.postal code == "123 456")}})
```

As you can see, the field postal code has a space, hence this request doesn't work and the error is:

```
2018-12-18T21:28:57.254-0500 E QUERY    [js] SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical @(shell):1:71
```

I tried replacing the expression "postal code" with something else that doesn't take a space, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to change that to `this['postal code']`